# What are the canon superhuman abilities of a Slayer in the Buffyverse?

Tags: magical-theory, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, powers

Joss Whedon's **Buffy the Vampire slayer** started off as a bit of a parody of the Vampire and damsel in distress narratives all the way back with the original movie in 1992. There, the titular heroine's abilities were kind of limited; she was unusually quick, agile, somewhat stronger than average, with hyper-motility and a n "early warning" sense that alerted her to the presence of vampires via a cramping in her lower abdomen:

It should be noted that the 1992 film is **not** quite held as canon; it has been included so as to have a proper basis for showing the character displaying supernatural abilities.

By 1997 and the a **much** more influential television series, however, the character, her role, her world's scope, and thus, her powers, were greatly expanded. The Slayer was now not just a Vampire hunter, but a Warrior defending against Supernatural evils", most usually female, who would stop all manner of demons, creatures, crisis, and dark threats. Vampires were simply her "bread and butter" prey.

In this version (to my knowledge) they retooled Buffy from the film by:

- removing her early warning sense,
- keeping her reflexes, agility and overall lack of fear
- increasing her strength, speed, fighting skill and durability

While portrayed somewhat inconsistent in the show, these increases were made to the point where even an untrained Slayer could bend steel. Buffy also seemed to have a minor healing factor, and an *uncanny* amount of luck in dangerous situations. These powers were no longer "inherited via reincarnation" or a "shared spirit" (as implied in the movie), but have a demonic origin...as in the first slayer was a human girl "imbued" with demon-like power specifically to fight demons by some ancient magical sect, and  now 1 girl in 1,000,000 possesses the "potential" to be a Slayer, with her powers being latent until something awakens it.

I know there is a comic book series as a continuation of the series, but I haven't followed it much. Considering this level of expansion, however, I figured a Slayer now has more defined capabilities. The TV show and Comic are **stated** to follow the same canon, so those media may provide a few specifics or parameters to what a Slayer's abilities may be. For example, Lorn, in the **Angel** spin off of the same universe can read people's futures in detail... but *only* if the person psychically "opens up" to him by singing.

So then:

**1.** What, in canon, are the exact powers and abilities of a Slayer, physical (**Example:** strength, speed, durability, agility, stamina), mental (**example:** sixth sense, demon sensing, will power) and spiritual (**example:** astral projection, healing others, etc)?

**2.** What, canonically, would be their weaknesses (**Example:** anything that specifically affects a Slayer or negates her abilities)and upper limits(**example:**  max weight, speed, damage taken, etc)?

Specific statements by characters, videos and panels examples pulled from the comic and show may be used, or supplementary data from media tied to or built around those or within the same canon can also be counted.

Comment: "Exact powers" is pretty vague. What are the "exact powers" of a human being, for example?

Comment: @Lexible Would you have a similar objection to "What are the exact powers of Scarlet Witch in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?"

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The level of restriction "in the MCU" is missing here, though.  OP references the original movie, the TV series and the comics, while actually noting that the powers appeared to change over time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes.

Comment: @DavidW My understanding is that the "Buffy verse" doesn't include the 1992 movie, but I'm not an expert so could well be wrong. The scope of the works involved doesn't seem to be Lexible's objection though, and I specifically included "in the MCU" to not be distracted by the fact that there are multiple versions of the Scarlet Witch character.

Comment: @Lexible Can you elaborate on *why*? Scarlet Witch seems to me to have a finite, easily listed set of powers. My limited knowledge of Buffy the Vampire Slayer suggests that's also the case here. Genuinely baffled why you think it's not specific enough of a question.

Comment: @Lexible Purposefully put "Exact " _because_ of the vagueness with which the show and comic (from the issues I've seen) handles it. Same reason I added the film (had no idea it was no longer considered canon); her abilities were ill defined there. In the series "power creep" would set in at points, with _various_ beings having super human power or potential, but then being stacked or augmented somehow; Angel, for instance, has vamp powers that on occasion were amped by his human soul or will. All versions of Spiderman have same "basic powers", for instance, but to **vastly** different degrees

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Elaboration is left as an exercise for the readers attempting to answer the question in my first comment.

Comment: @Lexible Check the changes; thought's appreciated.

Comment: “most usually female” — I think Slayers were always female?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was told there was an instance with a male Slayer in the comics. Due to my unfamiliarity, I can't say what issue. He had a sister who shared the powers, though.

Comment: @Russhiro aha, gotcha. I am entirely unfamiliar with the comics, I stand tentatively corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the original movie since lorewise it's kinda a desert (even if vampire Paul Reubens was absolutely hilarious).

According to the [Buffy wiki](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Slayer) being infused with the essence of a Shadow demon grants them the following abilities:

- Prophetic dreaming
- Dreams of the lives of past Slayers
- Ability to sense vampires and demons to an extent
- Innate hand-to-hand and weapons combat skills
- Superhuman strength
- Superhuman speed and reflexes
- Superhuman agility
- Superhuman stamina
- Superhuman durability
- Superhuman regeneration

As far as weaknesses go the Slayer is ultimately Human and has been drugged on occasion, setting an upper limit is kinda difficult since it ultimately comes down to plot convenience Buffy has on occasion taken beatings from baby vamps and on other occasions killed the BBEG of the episode while hardly breaking a sweat.

The thing is Buffy had a power that trumped all of these things and was in no way supernatural Buffy had the Power Of Friendship.

Comment: +1 specifically for the parenthetical about Paul Reubens! :D Also: Welcome SFF.SE!

Comment: Could you [edit] in the link to the wiki page where you got this information from?